# BigQuery on Bigtable - Pricing?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-bigtable

What is the pricing for BigQuery when we query data that is on Bigtable?

Every time when I write a query for Bigtable it would say:

> "This query will process 0B when run"

However, when the query finishes it says

> 10.440 sec elapsed, 359.17 MB processed

Do we get charged for 359.17 MB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you will be charged for the processing.

Based on the BigQuery [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing)

> You are charged for the number of bytes processed whether the data is
>   stored in BigQuery or in an external data source such as Cloud
>   Storage, Google Drive, or Cloud Bigtable.

Comment: Thanks! The pricing sheet is sometimes a bit confusing.